# carriwave, how clone object contain image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

the first I am using db mysql but then I change to postgres.

I write some function to clone db from sql to postgres. And I have a problem with clone db from Image table.

```
ImageClone.all.each do |p|
    img = Image.new()
    img.imageable_id = p.imageable_id
    img.imageable_type = p.imageable_type
    img.uploader = p.uploader
    puts p.uploader #=> 'testing_image.jpg'
    img.save
end



=> #<Image id: 1, imageable_id: 1, imageable_type: "ProductType", uploader: nil>
```

how can I set image url = 'testing_image.jpg'.
any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate an attachment into a new object you need to tell the new object to read the original attachment like so:

```
new_object.attachment_file = File.open(old_object.attachment_file.path)
```

Where `attachment_file` is the attribute defined as the mounted uploader in your attachment class:

```
class Object < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment_file, AttachmentUploader
```

And now your new object has the file loaded into memory. You can save it, validate it or discard it just like any other attachment!